# Error building MySQL Python module

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to build a Python mysql driver install for my Diskstation 1511 NAS (Intel Atom, Linux 2.6 embedded). I have MySQL-python-1.2.3. While MySQL is installed on the NAS it did not include the `mysql_config` utility so compiled a complete MySQL install.

When attempting to build I get the following error message (see further below).
Any help is appreciated.

```
DiskStation> python2.6 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
/opt/bin/gcc -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql-src/include/mysql -I/opt/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-src/include/mysql/my_config.h:1063:1: warning: "SIZEOF_OFF_T" redefined
In file included from /opt/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/opt/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:907:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
_mysql.c: In function '_escape_item':
_mysql.c:1050: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
_mysql.c: In function 'init_mysql':
_mysql.c:2836: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
_mysql.c:2838: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
_mysql.c:2840: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
_mysql.c:2842: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
/opt/bin/gcc -shared -L/opt/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o -L/usr/syno/mysql/lib/mysql -L/opt/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.so
/opt/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.2.1/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command '/opt/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I think thats the threadsafe client stuff... in your site.cfg file, can you set Threadsafe to false and see if that silences the error? did googling for mysqlclient_r not return anything useful?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same error above. The problem is that it lacks some of the header files. A quick Google show that it need `python-dev`, but it is for default Python (2.7). With python 2.6, there is a package `python2.6-dev`. So what we need is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

Comment: I having `Python2.7.2` to resolve the error I used `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev` worked fine.